# curl no URL specified using POST

Tags: rest, curl, fedora-commons

From a shell, I'm trying to use the REST API for Fedora Commons to upload a binary to a particular location using curl:

```
curl -X PUT --upload-file image.jpg -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" -H "http://localhost:8080/rest/TestUpload/newexcel"
```

The error I'm getting:

```
curl: no URL specified!
```

Following instructions from here:
https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/FEDORA471/RESTful+HTTP+API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-H` is for extra header to include in the request when sending HTTP to a server and you should not use it before the url.

You probably need to do `curl -X PUT --upload-file image.jpg -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg"  http://localhost:8080/rest/TestUpload/newexcel`